# Resize rectangle in Paper.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I have a very ordinary rectangle created in Paper.js and I'd like to resize it, but I can't find any obvious ways to do it.

```
var rect = new Rectangle([0, 0],[width,height]);
rect.center = mousePoint;
var path = new Path.Rectangle(rect, 4);
path.fillColor = fillColor;
path.meta = fillColor;
```

There's a scale transformation method, but it's not really for mouse interaction and my goal is to create a handle that can resize a component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the scaling by dividing the *intended* width/height of your rectangle with the *current* width/height of your rectangle.

Then you can use that scaling 'coefficient' to apply the scaling.

Based on your code above, you can get the current width/height of your rectangle by using: `rect.bounds.width` and `rect.bounds.height`

Here's a function you can use

```
var rectangle = new Shape.Rectangle({
    from: [0, 0],
    to: [100, 50],
    fillColor: 'red'
});


function resizeDimensions(elem,width,height){
    //calc scale coefficients and store current position
    var scaleX = width/elem.bounds.width;
    var scaleY = height/elem.bounds.height;
    var prevPos = new Point(elem.bounds.x,elem.bounds.y);

    //apply calc scaling
    elem.scale(scaleX,scaleY);

    //reposition the elem to previous pos(scaling moves the elem so we reset it's position);
    var newPos = prevPos + new Point(elem.bounds.width/2,elem.bounds.height/2);
    elem.position = newPos;
}


resizeDimensions(rectangle,300,200)
```

And here's the [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/dVLBboMwDP0VK5eCFhXabReqnrYPqNbLptIDC6ZEhQQloV1X9d8XEmBdq4GI5Bc/+z3jMxFZjSQh6z0aVhJKmMy7+JApUMhMJnYVwhIEHmFdZg1O3wY0OKcC7FMoWSewiSnEW+ohIy0wiy30PGIFr6oXWUmVwERhPknFJVykwr9FK5jhUtiemn/jK69RaBvrACus6ZHnpqQl8l1pwr5tFLGsYqDticAkFgVnHIXRkIkctJHKwq1SFoJGat6V98zOm6O9W2OudNR1mX7KVuR66pDFTeqHTfX9/+R66Cq5UXhYSd1PbCW5MME14YteR6ewpw6WsqapTjAa42LnbxzJCQm8cupV3fIVDlbBlOho9mc4VVy2uhtE0BeGWh5Q/6ZpCUfs5o8GuJnocWjhlT1ryrsbfD7849OPdU7vhxXNh4LubtS77Ivby4tfirtdGBeSPsZP9gtTYTf2U2G2bzoFmiQbMpuT7eUH) for it.

Be aware that the above function will also *reposition* the element at it's previous position but it will use top-left positioning. Paper.js uses the element's center to position them so I'm clarifying this so it doesn't cause confusion

Comment: Thank you very much. I just realized that there's a Shape object. I can call  `rectangle.set({ size: [200,200] })` and it works fine, but this is not the case for `Path.rectangle`.

Comment: I counter a problem with this solution. When I change the width to 0, then change it back, the scaleX is Infinity.

Comment: Good answer after this one.

Answer (score 18):

Note that PaperJS has **three** different kinds of Rectangles:

- **`Rectangle`** — This is the *basic type* (data structure) that defines a rectangle. Basically, top-left point, width, and height. (Nothing is displayed on the screen.) This kind of rectangle can be resized by setting its size property, for instance:

  ```
  let rect;
  const originalSize = [50, 50];
  const newSize = [100, 100];

  rect = new Rectangle([10, 50], originalSize);
  rect.size = newSize;
  ```
- **`Path.Rectangle`** — This is a method for generating a list of Segments that make up a rectangular-shaped Path. This *does* get displayed, but a Path lacks methods associated with a rectangle. For instance, a `Path.Rectangle` has no `size` property (so trying to modify it has no effect). To resize a Path you can use the `scale()` method as another answer proposes, or modify its *Segments*:

  ```
  rect = new Path.Rectangle([210, 50], originalSize);
  rect.strokeColor = "red";
  rect.strokeWidth = 3;

  rect.segments[0].point = rect.segments[0].point.add([-25, 25]);  // lower left point
  rect.segments[1].point = rect.segments[1].point.add([-25, -25]); // upper left point
  rect.segments[2].point = rect.segments[2].point.add([25, -25]);  // upper right point
  rect.segments[3].point = rect.segments[3].point.add([25, 25]);  // lower right point
  ```
- **`Shape.Rectangle`** — This kind of rectangle gets displayed *and* exposes properties about its shape, such as `size`. To resize a `Shape.Rectangle` you can modify its `size` property directly:

  ```
  rect = new Shape.Rectangle([410, 50], originalSize)
  rect.strokeColor = "blue"
  rect.strokeWidth = 3

  rect.size = newSize
  ```

Most likely, if you want to draw a rectangle *and* modify its properties after the fact, the rectangle you are looking for is **`Shape.Rectangle`**.

Here is a [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) that lets you play around with the different kinds of rectangles.

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted one.
Maybe there wasn't such shapes in the 2015 version...