# Resize rectangle "onResize" in paper.js

Tags: javascript, rectangles, paperjs

Ok, I feel incredibly stupid, but after trying for half an hour or so, I give up.

How do I resize a rectangle via the `onResize()` event in paper.js?
I am trying with [this example](http://paperjs.org/examples/boolean-operations/), which comes with a `onResize()` function already, but I am having no success (you can edit the sample by clicking on the `Source` button on the top right).

The current resize function looks like this:

```
function onResize() {
    text.position = view.center + [0, 200];
    square.position = view.center;
}
```

Now, I tried to make the square 80 % of the viewport height on resize by adding:

`square.size = [view.size.height / 100 * 80, view.size.height / 100 * 80];`

(I tried the same with static numbers, just to be sure).

I tried

`square.size = new Size(width, height);`

`square.set(new Point(view.center), new Size(width, height)`

```
square.height = height;
square.width = width;
```

and probably 20 more version that I cannot remember now.
When I console.logged the `square.size` it did show me the newly assigned values (sometimes?), but it still left the size of the rectangle unchanged.

What can I do to actually change the size of rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure, the `onResize()` function gets called whenever the window's dimensions change. That's not the only place you can change the rectangle's size / it has nothing to do with the rectangle per se.

To change the rectangle's sizes, you have to check the documentation. There's a `scale(amount)` and an `expand(amount)` method attached to the `Rectangle` object. `size` is just a property, and it doesn't seem to come with a setter.

Hence, if you want to keep a ratio in between the square and the view, I guess you could save the previous view width, see what the difference is and scale the rectangle accordingly – see how in this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29762862/7746498) answer to a previous question.

Alternatively, you could just reinitialise the square and set the size property to 80% of the view's width on each view resize:

```
square = new Path.Rectangle({
    position: view.center,
    size: view.bounds.width * 0.8,
    parent: originals,
    fillColor: 'white'
});
```

Comment: Thanks ibriq, that works. I think the `new Path.Rectangle` option seems the easier one compard to scale or expand. I still wonder, if you can set the position via `square.position = view.center;`, then why could you not do a similar thing with `square.size` ?